# Table name in a JSON array string

Tags: json, vb.net, datatable, json.net

I have a list of two `DataTable`s.  I'm converting this list to a JSON array, but I need to add the table name for every `DataTable` in the JSON string.

How can I do that?

This is how I'm converting the list:

```
Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, New DataTableConverter())
```

Desired JSON output:

```
{
    "category": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "desc": "default",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "desc": "fun",
        }
    ],
    "images": [
        {
            "image ID": "1",
            "link": "images/logo.jpg"
            "category": "1"
        },
        {
            "image ID": "2",
            "link": "images/logo2.jpg"
            "category": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you post an example of the JSON you'd like to get?

Comment: @onof i updated my question kindly check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting your tables into a `DataSet` instead of a list, then serialize the `DataSet`.

```
Dim table1 As New DataTable("category")
table1.Columns.Add("id", GetType(String))
table1.Columns.Add("desc", GetType(String))
table1.Rows.Add("1", "default")
table1.Rows.Add("2", "fun")

Dim table2 As New DataTable("images")
table2.Columns.Add("image ID", GetType(String))
table2.Columns.Add("link", GetType(String))
table2.Columns.Add("category", GetType(String))
table2.Rows.Add("1", "images/logo.jpg", "1")
table2.Rows.Add("2", "images/logo2.jpg", "2")

Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
dataSet.Tables.Add(table1)
dataSet.Tables.Add(table2)

Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented)

Console.WriteLine(json)
```

Output:

```
{
  "category": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "desc": "default"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "desc": "fun"
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "image ID": "1",
      "link": "images/logo.jpg",
      "category": "1"
    },
    {
      "image ID": "2",
      "link": "images/logo2.jpg",
      "category": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```